# How can I fix this Taskfile command?

Tags: api, curl, lambda, taskfile

I'm trying to test a local Lambda function using the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8` image. I having a problem with the proper escape/encoding for a curl POST to this API endpoint using `task`.

The API complains if the json payload is encoded:

```
[test] {"errorMessage": "Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)", "errorType": "Runtime.UnmarshalError", "stackTrace": []}
```

The `task` command complains if it is not:

```
yaml: line 7: did not find expected key
```

Here is `taskfile.yml`:

```
version: "3"

tasks:
    default:
        desc: Test the API
        cmds:
        - curl -XPOST http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -d '{'name': 'Todd'}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taskfile vomits on ":" in certain places (e.g. desc or cmds element).  You can try the following, using the pipe:

```
version: "3"

tasks:
    default:
        desc: Test the API
        cmds:
        - |
          curl -XPOST http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -d '{'name': 'Todd'}'
```

Comment: Wow. It's been so long since I asked this question that it might take me a while to verify this answer. Thanks for the potential solution!